# Improving Rock Extraction Analysis in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction

I've been experimenting with OpenCV and trying my hand at some image analysis with NASA images. My goal is to extract rocks from scenes from the Mars rovers. I've managed to extract a few, but the hit rate is pretty poor as seen in these pictures:

Original:

[image]

After Processing:

[image]

I have been using a Canny edge detector, finding the enclosed contours, and then filtering those by size. I have tried using some of the morphological operations like dilate and erode to help improve my hit rate, but it hasn't seemed to help.

Here is my attempt at extraction:

```
original_img = cv2.imread('mars_sample_image.jpg', 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(edited_img, 100, 200)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(edges, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

enclosed_contours = []
other_contours = []
for i in range(len(contours)):
    if hierarchy[0][i][0] < 0:
        enclosed_contours.append(contours[i])
    else:
        other_contours.append(contours[i])
contours = [contour for contour in enclosed_contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 100]
```

Any suggestions to increase my hit rate would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: next time draw edges in green or red, so they would more visible :D

Comment: Maybe try blob detection instead of Canny?

Comment: You should display each step of your computations, it helps a lot to fine-tune. I think the first problem is typically that canny won't find the whole contours of stones. Also have you tried a dilation followed by an erosion (a closing) ? to "close" those unclosed contours found by canny ? Show us :)